# Provide a $2$-tensor which is not decomposable on $\mathbb R^4$

Tags: abstract-algebra, tensor-products, tensors

**Definitions**:

A function $f:V^k\to \mathbb R$ is called a $k$-tensor if it takes $k$ members of a vector space $V$, as the input, and is linear with respect to each of the input elements.
For example, $f(\alpha v_1,\dots,v_k)=\alpha f(v_1,\dots,v_k)$ and $f(v_1+v',\dots,v_k)=f(v_1,\dots,v_k)+f(v',\dots,v_k)$

$L^k(V)$ denotes the set of all $k$-tensors on the vector space $V$.

Assume that $V$ is a vector space. We say $T \in L^2(V)$ is **decomposable** if there exist $A,B\in L^1(V)$ such that $T=A \otimes B$.

---

**Question**:

> On the vector space $\mathbb R^4$, Provide a $2$-tensor which is not
>   decomposable and prove your claim.

Note: My problem is that i don't know a way of finding such a $2$-tensor. If the question was about finding a decomposable $2$-tensor, I could just find two tensors and the product of them would be the answer. But it's not the case... So, I'm stuck on this...

Any idea?

Comment: So a simple tensor $u\otimes v$ will fail; but in general tensors will be linear combinations of these simple tensors. So how about one of the shape $u\otimes v+u'\otimes v'$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A tensor is well defined if it is defined on the vectors of a base, so take
$$
T(u_1,u_2)=T(u_2,u_1)=1\\
T(u_i,u_j)=0,\ \text{otherwise}
$$
If it was decomposable, then
$$
\exists a,b:\\
T(u_1,u_2)=a(u_1)b(u_2)=1\\
T(u_2,u_1)=a(u_2)b(u_1)=1
$$
but
$$
T(u_1,u_1)=a(u_1)b(u_1)=0
$$
so that $a(u_1)=0\ \lor\ b(u_1)=0$, a contradiction.